# cbind before rbind, or rbind before cbind?

Tags: h2o, bigdata

Say I have 20 frames on a 4-node H2O cluster: a1..a5, b1..b5, c1..c5, d1..d5. And I want to combine them into one big frame, from which I will build a model.

Is it better to combine sets of columns, then combine rows:

```
h2o.rbind(
  h2o.cbind(a1, b1, c1, d1),
  h2o.cbind(a2, b2, c2, d2),
  h2o.cbind(a3, b3, c3, d3),
  h2o.cbind(a4, b4, c4, d4),
  h2o.cbind(a5, b5, c5, d5)
  )
```

Or, to combine the rows first, then the columns:

```
h2o.cbind(
  h2o.rbind(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5),
  h2o.rbind(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5),
  h2o.rbind(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5),
  h2o.rbind(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5)
  )
```

For the sake of argument, 1/2/3/4/5 might each represent one month of data, which is why they got imported separately. And a/b/c/d are different sets of features, which again explains why they were imported separately. Let's say, a1..a5 have 1728 columns, b1..b5 have 113 columns, c1..c5 have 360 columns, and d1..d5 is a single column (the answer I'll be modelling). (Though I suspect, as H2O is a column database, that the relative number of columns in a/b/c/d does not matter?)

By "better" I mean quicker, but if there is a memory-usage difference in one or the other, that would also be good to know: I'm mainly interested in the Big Data case, where the combined frame is big enough that I wouldn't be able to fit it in the memory of just a a single node.

Comment: Always useful to receive a comment with your downvote. Otherwise, how am I supposed to know what isn't clear, or needs fixing?

Answer (score 3):

I'm now fairly sure the answer is: doesn't matter.

**Point 1:** The two examples in the question are identical. This is because both h2o.cbind() and h2o.rbind() use lazy evaluation. So either way it returns immediately, and nothing happens until you perform some operation. (I've been using `nrow()` or `ncol()` to force creation of the new frame - it also allows me to check that I've got what I expected.)

**Point 2:** I've been informed by an H2O developer that they is no difference (CPU or memory), because either way the data will be copied.

**Point 3:** I've not noticed any significant speed difference on some reasonably big cbind/rbinds, with final frame size of 17GB (compressed size). This has not been rigorous, but I've never waited more than 30 to 40 seconds for the `nrow()` command to complete the copy.

**Bonus Tip:** Following on from point 1, it is essential you call `nrow()` (or whatever) to force the copy to happen, *before* you delete the constituent parts. If you do the `all = rbind(parts)`, then `h2o.rm(parts)`, then `nrow(all)` you get an error (and your data is lost and needs to be imported again).